# How to make theme elements customizable in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, menus, customization, themes

In Wordpress there's a menu option called 'Appeareances'.
I want to add (e.g.) a submenu 'header' there and then be able to customize the header from within wordpress (administration page).

From what I understood I have to have a 'functions.php' file in my theme folder. In the 'functions.php' file I write something like this:

```
<?php add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function); ?>
```

Of course with adapted arguments (which I'm not entirely sure what those should be since I feel quite lost in all this).

Comment: Why not use the [Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)?

Comment: Because I didn't know about :P I'll look into it, thanks for the link. As of now, I think that the following function call in the functions.php file probably is a step in the right direction: `add_theme_support('custom-header');`

Answer (score 1):

As per comments: this is what the Customizer API is for. In the case of the [header](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) there are a dozen parameters to tweak the behaviour with. Like this:

```
$defaults = array(
    'default-image'          => '',
    'width'                  => 0,
    'height'                 => 0,
    'flex-height'            => false,
    'flex-width'             => false,
    'uploads'                => true,
    'random-default'         => false,
    'header-text'            => true,
    'default-text-color'     => '',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );
```